# Incorrect type. Expected "array"

Tags: json, electron

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que esto es lo que no me permite compilar mi app de electronjs
me he tirado tres dias, pero no comprendo como ponerlo en arreglo o lo que me pide, me pueden ayudar?

Comment: probaste con poner []?

Comment: si y no, pienso que es algo mas complejo que eso

Comment: creo que esta mal los comandos